# Ajax updating content from database and display when button clicked

Tags: html, mysql, ajax

I have a "recruit" button where, when button is clicked via Ajax it has to update the database to "invited" and then the same button should display *Invited* which is updated to the database. By default the database contains "recruit".

This action happens when button is clicked it updates the database as invited, but another button appears called invited. The recruit button is also there. 
This is my code.

```
  <div id='submit_wrp'>        
  <input id='btn_submit' type='submit' class='btn btn-primary active' value= " . $rowchk['recruit'] . "/>
  </div>   ";
 <input type="hidden" type="number" id='REC' value='<?php echo $id ?>'/>
<script>
    $('#btn_submit').click(function () {
        var name = $('#REC').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            // url: 'testing.php',
            url: 'testing.php?REC=' + name,
            data: 'REC=' + name,
            success: function () {
                // alert("success" + name);
                $('#submit_wrp').load(location.href + ' #btn_submit');

                ///$('#submit_wrp').html(response);




            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error" + name);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use a form submit event OR change the button to a button
2. after you click you replace the div content with the div containing the submit button from the same page you are on.

So perhaps you mean

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#formID').on("submit",function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var name = $('#REC').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        // url: 'testing.php',
        url: 'testing.php?REC=' + name,
        data: 'REC=' + name,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#submit_wrp').html(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error" + name);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>

<form id="formID">
  <div id='submit_wrp'>        
   <input id='btn_submit' type='submit' class='btn btn-primary active' value= " . $rowchk['recruit'] . "/>
  </div>   ";
  <input type="hidden" type="number" id='REC' value='<?php echo $id ?>'/>
</form>
```

Comment: what is #formID related to? from html

Comment: `<form id="formID">` - see the bottom of my answer

Comment: I have tried  $('#submit_wrp').html(data); so when I click on the button the button disappears but the updated content doesn't display. When I reload the page I get Recruit and Invited buttons

Comment: You need to send whatever you need from the PHP. If not, then do not change the html but instead do `$('#btn_submit').val("Invited");` in the success